# MySql- Update using like between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, inner-join

I've two tables... say Blocks and Process

Process:

```
    P_ID    P_NAME
    ----    ------
   1     x1p1 
   2     x1p4 
   3     x1p8 
   4     x2p1 
   5     x3p4 
   6     x3py
```

Blocks:

```
B_ID           BLOCK_NAME                     P_ID  
------   -------------------------------     ------
     1     x1p1ef......ldoddr60maew......    (null)
     2     x1p4fr......ldoddr60mans......    (null)
     3     x1p8jg......ldoddr80maew......    (null)
     4     x1p4gh......ldoddr80mans......    (null)
     5     x1p8mj......ldoyyyyy20ma......    (null)
     6     x2p1ad......ldoyyyyy30maisclk.... (null)
     7     x3p4da......ldoyyyyy30ma......    (null)
     8     x3p4we......ldozzzzz20ma......    (null)
     9     x3pxtu......ldozzzzz40ma......    (null)
    10     x3pxte......ldozzzzz60ma......    (null)
```

P_ID in Blocks table is Foreign Key referencing to P_ID in Process table which is the Primary key.

Now I want to update the values of Blocks.P_ID = Process.P_ID if the Blocks.BLOCK_NAME is **like** Process.P_NAME

I tried

```
UPDATE Blocks INNER JOIN Process 
ON (Blocks.BLOCK_NAME=Process.P_NAME) 
SET Blocks.P_ID=Process.P_ID 
WHERE Blocks.BLOCK_NAME LIKE CONCAT('%',Process.P_NAME,'%')
```

The table gets updated with Blocks.P_ID as 1 for all the records.
I get Blocks table as:

```
B_ID           BLOCK_NAME                     P_ID  
------   -------------------------------     ------
     1     x1p1ef......ldoddr60maew......      1
     2     x1p4fr......ldoddr60mans......      1 
     3     x1p8jg......ldoddr80maew......      1
     4     x1p4gh......ldoddr80mans......      1
     5     x1p8mj......ldoyyyyy20ma......      1
     6     x2p1ad......ldoyyyyy30maisclk....   1
```

But I'm expecting this:

```
B_ID           BLOCK_NAME                     P_ID  
------   -------------------------------     ------
     1     x1p1ef......ldoddr60maew......      1
     2     x1p4fr......ldoddr60mans......      2 
     3     x3p4jg......ldoddr80maew......      5
     4     x1p4gh......ldoddr80mans......      2
     5     x1p8mj......ldoyyyyy20ma......      3
     6     x2p1ad......ldoyyyyy30maisclk....   4
```

I don't know where I went wrong... Can anybody help me out??
Thanks in advance...!!

Comment: What is your Question? and if you have try some code then share with us.

Comment: Please post some relevant code and a specific question as to what do you want.

Comment: I think my question is clear enough after the first edit.. why is it on hold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very close.

You should've used either ANSI join syntax and put the `LIKE` condition in `ON` clause

```
UPDATE blocks b JOIN process p
    ON b.block_name LIKE CONCAT(p.p_name, '%')
   SET b.p_id = p.p_id;
```

or implicit comma join syntax and put the condition in `WHERE` clause

```
UPDATE blocks b, process p
   SET b.p_id = p.p_id
 WHERE b.block_name LIKE CONCAT(p.p_name, '%');
```

Another way to do it

```
UPDATE blocks b JOIN process p
    ON p.p_name = LEFT(b.block_name, CHAR_LENGTH(p.p_name))
   SET b.p_id = p.p_id;
```

Outcome:

```
+------+-----------------------------------+------+
| B_ID | BLOCK_NAME                        | P_ID |
+------+-----------------------------------+------+
|    1 | x1p1ef......ldoddr60maew......    | 1    |
|    2 | x1p4fr......ldoddr60mans......    | 2    |
|    3 | x1p8jg......ldoddr80maew......    | 3    |
|    4 | x1p4gh......ldoddr80mans......    | 2    |
|    5 | x1p8mj......ldoyyyyy20ma......    | 3    |
|    6 | x2p1ad......ldoyyyyy30maisclk.... | 4    |
|    7 | x3p4da......ldoyyyyy30ma......    | 5    |
|    8 | x3p4we......ldozzzzz20ma......    | 5    |
|    9 | x3pxtu......ldozzzzz40ma......    | NULL |
|   10 | x3pxte......ldozzzzz60ma......    | NULL |
+------+-----------------------------------+------+
```

Comment: thanks @peterm the query worked as expected... I think my query was  complex...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Blocks B 
INNER JOIN PROCESS P ON B.BLOCK_NAME LIKE CONCAT(P.P_NAME + '%')
SET B.P_ID=P.P_ID;
```